# Speed up multilple matrix products with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In python I have 2 three dimensional arrays:

`T` with size `(n,n,n)`

`U` with size `(k,n,n)`

`T` and `U` can be seen as many 2-D arrays one next to the other. I need to multiply all those matrices, ie I have to perform the following operation:

```
for i in range(n):
        H[:,:,i] =  U[:,:,i].dot(T[:,:,i]).dot(U[:,:,i].T)
```

As `n` might be very big I am wondering if this operation could be in some way speed up with numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carefully looking into the iterators and how they are involved in those dot product reductions, we could translate all of those into one [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) implementation like so -

```
H = np.einsum('ijk,jlk,mlk->imk',U,T,U)
```